# PreferenceScreen has no child tags

Tags: android, preferencescreen

For some strange reason I am getting this strange error when I do ctrl+space on a prefferenceScreen.xml

> The errors are: PreferenceScreen has no child tags & PreferenceScreen has no known child tags

I am using eclipse.

How do you fix this? or should I just code over it and hope I don't make spelling errors.

Comment: sdfwer, I understood that has happened. Probably you tried put the preference layout XML file in `res/layout` folder. When we are working with preferences, we need put the preference file in `res/xml` folder. I had the same problem, but I tried add the preference file again and I perceived that I could change the *Resource Type* on *New Android XML File* window. When I changed the *Resource Type* and I confirmed the window, the file was created and the tags were recognized. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked without the need for the library help. Although I still find it strange that some other projects do have auto-help for different types such as EditTextPreference or CheckBoxPreference.